# Basic Question about @track decorator

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, track

I have a (probably very) basic question about @track decorator.

I modified the helloExpressions LW Component from Sample Gallery as below. Here the values FirstName and lastName are no longer decorated as **Tracked** properties. I am adding their concatenated value to another tracked property **capitalFullName**.

I do not have the contributing factors for '**uppercasedFullName**' tracked, still this updates the UI for both output values **uppercasedFullName** and **capitalFullName** when **firstname** or **lastname** are updated from input screen. However if I remove track decorator for **capitalFullName**, the UI refresh stops working. If I am not tracking the direct contributors **uppercasedFullName**, why does it still work when I am using them somewhere else with a **tracked** property?

JavaScript File

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloExpressions extends LightningElement
{
    firstName = '';
    lastName = '';
    @track capitalFullName;

    handleChange(event)
    {
        const field = event.target.name;
        if (field === 'firstName')
        {
            this.firstName = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'lastName')
        {
            this.lastName = event.target.value;
        }

        this.capitalFullName = this.firstName + ' <--> ' + this.lastName;
        this.capitalFullName = this.capitalFullName.trim().toUpperCase();
    }

    get uppercasedFullName()
    {
        console.log('inside uppercasedFullName = ' + this.firstName);
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`.trim().toUpperCase();

    }
}
```

HTML File:

```
 <template>
    <lightning-card title="HelloExpressions" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input name="firstName" label="First Name" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input name="lastName" label="Last Name" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
            <p class="slds-m-top_medium">
                Uppercased Full Name: {uppercasedFullName}
            </p>
            <p class="slds-m-top_medium">
                Capital Full Name: {capitalFullName}
            </p>
        </div>

        <c-view-source source="lwc/helloExpressions" slot="footer">
            Use JavaScript expressions in a template. Type something in the
            input fields to see the recipe in action.
        </c-view-source>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: I found something additional on this. Not sure if it is designed this way or a bug, but looks like when I have at-least one tracked property on UI, it refreshes the whole UI.

If I add another non-tracked property with all features, assignments similar to 'capitalFullName' and show it up on UI; even that value is updated. Considering, this new property is not tracked and its contributing properties are not tracked, i should not be seeing any updates for that property on UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triggering any @track variable results in all merge fields being recalculated to see if the DOM needs to be updated. Only nodes that actually have changed values result in those nodes being updated in the DOM. This is why, when you remove the last @track, nothing gets updated, otherwise everything gets updated when capitalFullName is updated. I wouldn't say this is "unexpected" behavior, it's just not really clearly documented. You'd need to look at the source code to get a better idea of what's going on. I'm not sure, but [this file](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/blob/55b962b61a8d38495a9d4584d5315a0fd2ab1d50/docs/architecture/README.md) might help you understand better.

Comment: Thanks **sfdcfox**. I will read the link thoroughly this week. You answer does makes sense to me. I also tried removing the tracked property from HTML file and kept rest of the properties as is, as expected nothing was updated.

While the documentation does mention this line **"When a component rerenders, all the expressions used in the template are reevaluated."**, it was not completely clear to me. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_private_reactive